# How hard is it to upgrade an Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Let's imagine I create an Azure virtual machine. Say a small one initially.

Later on I decide that the perf of this machine isn't cutting it. I want to upgrade to a larger machine more powerful one.

Given that I've already fully configured this machine to work the way I need it to, **how quickly \ easily can it be upgraded so say a medium machine?**

Comment: I disagree with this question being closed, as the solution (at least the one I proposed) involves PowerShell, which in turn sits atop the Windows Azure REST API, which (in my opinion) falls within the realm of programming, even if only peripherally. And... may people build tools to automate this, whether calling PowerShell, Linux command-line script equivalent, or REST endpoint directly.

Comment: I just found myself at this question. I think it's a good one and deserved re-opening on principle! (+1)

Comment: @DavidMakogon if the answer needs some coding, it should be mentioned in the question. Chances are I'd be more happy to reopen were that in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is very easy. You go to the portal and *configure/settings/virtual machine size*.
The instance will reboot once (depending on your application that can be an issue or take time) and the virtual hardware will be changed.

Comment: +1 important. As a side point, we were not sure if we would lose our apps and data if we upgraded. We found out by doing.

Comment: @DaveA Sorry, just want to be clean.  Did your apps need to be reinstalled?

Comment: @NullReference, clean upgrade. and downgrade. and upgrade again. specs of the VM can change without apps being interrupted.

Answer (score 7):

From PowerShell, changing Virtual Machine size is trivial:

```
Set-AzureVMSize [-InstanceSize] <String> -VM <IPersistentVM> [ <CommonParameters>]
```

You then need to call `Update-AzureVM` to have the changes take effect. So... to go from Small to Medium, you can retrieve your VM information, update the size, and then update the VM based on the size change:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "YourServiceName" -Name "yourVMName" | Set-AzureVMSize "Medium" | Update-AzureVM
```

See full documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152814.aspx).